# Can someone confirm the Lao language tones in the greeting "sabaidi"

Tags: tone, lao, thai

In Thai สบายดี is sà-bāɪ-dīː(sà with a low tone, bāɪ and dī with mid tones).

In Lao ສະບາຍດີ is sá-bàɪ-dìː (sá with a high tone, bàɪ and dìː with low tones).

Okay, I need confirmation on the tones in Lao. The Thai "sabaidi" is confirmed and good. I keep getting difference of opinion on the Lao "sabaidi". I am looking for the tones as spoken in the Vientiane dialect of Lao.

For Thai tones, I am using 1) Mid 2) Low 3) Falling 4) High 5) Rising

For Lao tones, I am using 1) Mid 2) Low 3) High Falling 4) Low Falling 5) High 6) Rising

Comment: This question seems to be very language-specific, plus it requests for a general knowledge. The official tones are High, Low Rising, and Low Rising: ສະ is a High class + short vowel, ບາຍ is Mid class + voiced final, and ດີ is Mid class + Long vowel.

Comment: Yes I have to agree this is a language question rather than a linguistics question. Sadly there is only a proposal with 4 followers for **[Thai Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60120/thai-language-usage)**, there is also a **[Languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46787/languages)** proposal with 53 followers, but it has been stalled for some time unfortunately. I am following both though, so why not throw your support behind them too?